# How to Sum the Values for Each Category of a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

Say I have a csv file that lists the amount of money spent on different brands of smartphones, Ex:

```
Apple, 960
Samsung, 600
Motorola, 130
Apple, 800
Samsung, 300
Google, 240
Motorola, 130
Apple, 640
```

How would I compile the amount of money spent on each brand so that it ultimately looks like:

```
Apple, 1600
Samsung, 2000
Google, 700
Motorola, 1200
```

This is a very simplified example, and my actual dataset is much larger and more complicated than this, but I still want to know how I could go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Shouldn't apple sum to 2400?

Answer (score 0):

You can import `csv` files into python via `pandas.read_csv('file_path')` which will return dataframes.

What you're looking for is `DataFrame.groupby()`

Let `df` be the dataframe created by reading your csv file

`df.groupby('brands').sum()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to do it quickly -

```
import pandas as  pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", names=["brand", "money"])
df.groupby("brand").sum()
```

Result -

```
    money
brand
Apple      2400
Google      240
Motorola    260
Samsung     900
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a library to perform this work, I would recommend these steps in your python code:

1. Create an empty dictionary of brands and sums
2. Read a line from the csv
3. Split that string by commas, storing the result in an array
4. Check if the first element in that array exists in your dictionary
5. a. if it exists, find the corresponding value in your dictionary and add to the existing value

   b. If it does not exist, add an item to your dictionary with the value

Repeat until the you reach the end of the file.